# Ignite 2: Calling an Async Runnable Stops Executing After an Hour

Tags: ignite

This worked fine with Ignite 1.7.  Recently upgraded to 2 and noticed that calling 
`grid.compute().withAsync().run([my runnable here])`

stops working after about an hour.  That gets called about once a minute and executes a short-lived runnable on the cluster.  After about an hour, calling that above does nothing.

No warnings, no errors, it just does nothing.

Comment: I should have noted, this is the Java version of Ignite.

Comment: is it possible to create a reproducer for the issue? if yes, could you please upload it and send us a link for it?

Comment: Sounds like a thread starvation. Did you check thread dumps?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly!  That's exactly what I did first, made an independent test program to try to reproduce (or not) the problem.  Locally and on the production server, my test runs for many hours without stopping.  It's only in production where this keeps happening.

@ValentinKulichenko, that's my feeling too.  Investigating that now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with Ignite 2.0, which makes me very happy.

I had a particular scenario where a semaphore after about an hour's worth of running would block a thread which ended-up blocking what the runnables were doing.